# 「2日」をひらがなで書くと「2つか」？それとも「2か」？

Tags: written-language

「2日」・「二日」が標準の書き方で、全部ひらがなで「ふつか」と書く場合も、もちろんありますね。数字とひらがなを混ぜて書く場合は日付をどうやって書きますか？

それとも、ひらがなで書くと必ず数字と混ぜない決まりはありますか？

例えば子供がひらがなで日記を書いたら日付をどうやって書きますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

＞それとも、ひらがなで書くと必ず数字と混ぜない決まりはありますか？

特に決まりはありません。

＞例えば子供がひらがなで日記を書いたら日付をどうやって書きますでしょうか？

子供の年齢にもよりますが、６歳未満、つまり小学校入学前の場合、「ついたち　ふつか」という言い方自体に抵抗がありますので、日記帳などを見ると

（　　　　　がつ　　　　　　にち）

とあり、単純にその中に数字を入れます。

小学校に入ると、一年生で漢字を習うとともに「ついたち」「ふつか」という読みを習います。この時点で、黒板にある四月三日に　しがつ　みっか　等と読み仮名を書くとことから始まります。

つまり、幼少期は　４　がつ　３　にち　でＯＫです。小学校で漢字を習ったら、四月三日と書いてしがつみっか、と読めるようになりましょう。

Answer (score 2):

もちろん、「二日」「２日」「ふつか」のように書くほうがわかりやすくて一般的だと思いますが、あえて数字とひらがなを混ぜて書くとしたら、「２か」「二か」「２かかん」「二かかん」などのようにすると思います。（試しにパソコンで「２か」「２かかん」と打つと「二日」「二日間」に変換されますが、「２つか」「２つかかん」と打つと「二日」「二日間」に変換されません。）

Comment: ちなみに「三日、四日、五日」も「３か、４か、５か」で変換されますが「３っか、４っか、５つか」では無理です。「一日」は「ついたち」か「１にち」とかじゃないと無理です